# pass state data to product details page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i have item display component which displays all items from an api. When i click on the products, i want to transfer the state through the link to the product display page so i can view the details of only the product i clicked on. Here is the code
PRODUCT LIST

````
            return <div key={item.id} className="col-md-6">
                <div className="listing">
                    <div className="listing-thumbnail">
                        <Link  to={{
                                pathname: `listingdetails/${item.id}`,
                                state:{
                                    items: this.state.items
                                }
                            }}><img src={ item.images[0]} alt="listing" /></Link>
                        <div className="listing-badges">``` please help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "query".

```
<Link  to={{
  pathname: `listingdetails/${item.id}`,
  query:{
    items: this.state.items
  }
}}>
```

And you can use it like this.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    item: props.location.query.items
  }
}
```

Comment: When i do that i get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: Have you defined a route for 'listingdetails' page?
e.g: 
<Switch>
  <Route path='/listingdetails/:id' component={Listingdetails}/>
</Switch>

Comment: yes, what do i need to import to use query